# Como "tipar" objetos aninhados? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, objetos

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto de exemplo:

```
const types: any = {
            car: { full: 'fullString', empty: 'emptyString' },
            plane: 'myString',
};
```

Estou tentando colocar um tipo no *types* porém o objeto aninhado **(car)**, ele considera que não é o tipo correto.
Ex:

```
const types: {[key:string]: string} = {
                car: { full: 'fullString', empty: 'emptyString' },
                plane: 'myString',
    };
```

Como devo tipar para que ele considere o objeto aninhado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está usando typescript e deseja fazer um melhor uso de tipos, especialmente para objetos, o melhor a se fazer é usar uma interface, exemplo:

```
interface MinhaInterface{
   car: {
     full: string,
     empty: string
   },
   plane: string
}
```

E então usar a mesma do seguinte modo:

```
const types: MinhaInterface = {
  ...
}
```

Desta maneira você vai obter ajuda do intellisense que irá te dizer se você se esqueceu alguma propriedade e também se o valor passado para uma propriedade é diferente do esperado.

Com o exemplo acima você pode fazer um refactor e transformar por exemplo o objeto que `car` recebe como valor em uma interface própria em caso de necessidade, exemplo:

```
interface Car{
   full: string,
   empty: string
}

interface MinhaInterface{
   car: Car,
   plane: string
}
```

O problema no seu código é que passando `[key:string]: string` como tipo você dizendo para que o tipo da sua variável é um objeto composto por uma chave de tipo `string` e que cada chave pode conter um valor que também deve ser `string`, que não será sempre verdade no seu caso visto que `car` é a sua vez um objeto. Se você deseja fazer do seu modo o que pode ser feito é:

```
const types: {[key:string]: string | object} = {
    car: { full: 'fullString', empty: 'emptyString' },
    plane: 'myString',
}
```

Com isso o compilador não deve apontar erros visto que agora as suas chaves podem contem valores de tipo `string` ou `object`, mas honestamente não tem sentido usar typescript se você não vai fazer uso dos tipos no melhor modo possível.